# Where to send JWT Tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I'm using JWT for user login/signup and I had a question about sending/receiving the token.

Currently, I'm storing the token as a property in a JSON Object starting in the server, then I send it to the front-end. After the client receives the object it stores the token as a cookie. Every POST request from the client to the server will have a token property in it's body, and the response from the server will have the token as a property also.

Is this okay, or should I be sending the token as a header in the requests/responses?

Using: React (+DOM), JavaScript, Express, Node.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing JWT token in Cookie is good enough. You don't need to send to token in the request body or return in response.

**Good practice**

1. Store JWT in cookie with mode `http-only` and `is-secure: true` so javascript can't see this token, and only transfer the token using https security layer.
2. Add a custom request header in every ajax request and verify this header in backend to advoid crsf attack.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys coming back to this post to add some more information for those who are in the same situation I was.

When using fetch to send requests to your backend, make sure you add

```
credentials: 'same-origin'
```

to your fetch options object in order to send/receive cookies to/from the server.
I used cookieParser in node backend code to send/receive cookies. Make sure to at least make them http-only and include any other security options you need or want.